# Single Activity и BottomNavigationView

Tags: android

Надумываю перейти на Single Activity style.
Возникают следующие вопросы:

1. Как быть с DrawerMenu / ToolBar / BottomNavigatioView

Например, есть вложенные фрагменты в которых мы должны показывать в место бургера кнопку назад и в этом фрагменте не должны быть никаких BottomNavigationView и DrawerMenu.

Как они скрываются? Может у Navigation component или у чего то еще есть написанные методы для реализации этого поведения?
Или все же нужно подписаться на "FragmentChangeListener" и самому рулить всеми состояниями "общих" контролов (BottomNavigationView & DrawerMenu). + еще где то нужно показывать Toolbar, где-то нет, еще в каком то фрагменте он может быть совсем других форм и содержания...

2. Стоит ли оно того?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Никаких общих компонентов нет на эту тему. Вы должны сами "рулить" всем этим.

Вы можете создать какой-то интерфейс вроде такого:

```
interface ToolBarListener {

    void setToolbar(toolbarTitle: String)
    // так же могут быть и другие методы вроде этого. 
}
```

реализовать его в Activity и передавать его экземпляр в каждый фрагмент и когда фрагмент инициализируется то задает состояние `Activity`.

Если состояние намного более сложное чем просто тайтл или наличие бургера, то я бы создал штуку вроде такой:

```
interface ActivityStateListener {

    void setActivityState(state: ActivityState)
    // так же могут быть и другие методы вроде этого. 
}

class ActivityState {

     String toolbarTitle;
     boolean isHamburgerVisible;
     boolean isBottomNavVisisble;
     boolean isLockNavDrawer;
     // и так далее
}
```

Стоит ли? Ну это вопрос субъективный. С фрагментами работать легче, но сказать, что вы получите какой-то кардинальный прирост, думаю что нет. Если ваш проект не большой и вам хочется получить это удобство, то может и стоит.

Comment: Я понял, спасибо. Но рассчитывал, что гугл все таки сделал какой то стандарт, а не как обычно, делать костыль. Сам гугл предлагает такой вариант (в конце статьи. тоже похоже на костыль) https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-ui

Comment: Ну почему костыль то? Фрагмент это не сущность которая должна занимать целый экран. Вы можете их хоть по 5 штук на экран делать( я вот недавно даже список делал из них). Это вполне нормальное решение. Когда есть какой-то хост (activity), и есть дети. К тому же пилить что-то сюда смысла мало, это очень просто реализуется самому и настраивается под свои нужды

Comment: Ну хотелось бы чего то типа AppBarConfiguration. Вот там подумали про topLevelDestination. А про такие элементарные кейсы как скрытие показ всяких toolbar/bottomnavigation не подумали (ну или оставили на откуп разработчику), хотя понятное дело в SingleActivity pattern без этого никак(гугл же советует переходить на SingleActivity). Может Вы и правы по поводу 5 штук и т.п...

Comment: Хотя, если использовать addOnDestinationChangedListener , то это похоже на использование AppBarConfiguration. Только нет инкапсуляции внутри какого то отдельного объекта..